# Is it true that ${^\infty}{\sqrt[x]{x}} = x$

Tags: tetration

I was fiddling around with tetration and I stumbled across an interesting idea, ${^\infty}{\sqrt[x]{x}}$. I messed around with the concept a little bit and I had the following idea:

Let ${^\infty}y = x$, then
$$
{^\infty}y = x = y^x
$$
Now we have
$$
x = y^x,\\
y = \sqrt[x]{x}
$$
Thus
$$
\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^\cdots}} = x
$$
I think it makes sense, but I'm not entirely sure if it's right or not. Plugging in some values for x and shoving it into a recursive function in python showed that it worked for $x = 2$, but at $x = 3$ it converged at $2.478051576300804$. I'm not sure if this is because my identity is false or because floating-point precision isn't precise enough. So is this statement true?

Comment: To the person who down-voted, care to explain why?

Comment: I think people are downvoting because this is considered to be a "well-known" problem (which is arrogant if you ask me).  I upvoted because the problem shows some critical thought on the part of OP, and it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not only true, but mentioned explicitly in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) on the subject. :-) In fact, it has been known since the time of Euler. What you forgot to add is that *infinite tetration* only converges for $x\in\Big[e^{-e}~,~\sqrt[e]e\Big]$.

Comment: Oh so that's where the down-votes were coming from. Why does it converge for $x \in [e^{-e}, \sqrt[e]{e}]$?

Comment: Because $\sqrt[x]x$ has a global maximum in $x=e$. Also, notice that $e^{-e}=\sqrt[1/e]{1/e}$ .